# Access DISTANCE SOQL Result in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, soql, query, geolocation

I am trying to access the result of a DISTANCE SOQL Query in visualforce but I cannot figure out how to do this.  The correct values do appear in debugging.  Below is my relevant code:

Controller:

```
engineers = Database.query(
                             'SELECT First_Name__c, Skills__c,  Last_Name__c, Division__c, ' +
                             'Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s, ' +
                             'DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(' + lat + ',' + lng + '), \'mi\') Miles ' +
                             'FROM Remote_Engineer__c WHERE Name != null');

for (Remote_Engineer__c eng : engineers) {
        System.debug(eng.get('Miles'));
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Engineers" id="results">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!engineers}" var="e">
        <apex:column headerValue="First Name" title="Engineer First Name">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!e.Id}">{!e.First_Name__c}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" title="Engineer Last Name">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.Last_Name__c}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column  headerValue="Division" title="Division">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.Division__c}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column  headerValue="State" title="State">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.State__c}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Skills" title="Skills">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.Skills__c}" />
        </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Latitude" title="Latitude">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.Location__Latitude__s }" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Longitude" title="Longitude">
            <apex:outputField value="{!e.Location__Longitude__s }" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Miles" title="Miles">
            <apex:outputtext value="{!e.Miles}" />
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Things I have tried:

- Replaced apex:outputField to apex:outputtext to fix this error:

  Could not resolve field 'Miles' from  value binding
  '{!e.Miles}' in page VenueRemoteLookup
- Replaced {!e.Miles} with {!e['Miles']} which will compile correctly (I am using sublime and mavensmate), but when viewing the visualforce page I get the following error:

  Could not resolve field 'Miles' from  value binding
  '{!e['Miles']}' in page venueremotelookup

Comment: Shouldn't your query return a `List<AggregateResult>` rather than any other SObject?

Comment: @CharlesT Have you tried it? You will get a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet confirmed this is a feature gap, but you can certainly use a wrapper class. Here's a simple demo:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class DemoController
{
    public List<AccountWrapper> wrappers { get; private set; }

    public DemoController()
    {
        wrappers = new List<AccountWrapper>();
        for (Account record : [
            SELECT Name, DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance
            FROM Account WHERE BillingLatitude != null
        ]) wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(record));
    }

    public class AccountWrapper
    {
        public Account record { get; private set; }
        public Decimal distance { get; private set; }
        public AccountWrapper(Account record)
        {
            this.record = record;
            this.distance = (Decimal)record.get('distance');
        }
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="DemoController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
            <apex:column value="{!wrapper.record.Name}" headerValue="Name" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Distance">
                <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.distance}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You beat me. I am in the middle of writing this answer :).

Comment: This issue seems similar (but not identical) to this `Known Issue`: [SOQL result which uses Distance function is in VF view state causes ISE](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008e1TAAQ).

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried your query to reference a geolocation field on the parent and I get "No such column 'distance' on entity".  I have no trouble referencing it if I directly query the parent. Is it not possible to do this query starting at the child level and going up to the parent?