# SOQL distance of a parent field not working

Tags: apex, soql, child-to-parent

I am opening this question after reading this: [Access DISTANCE SOQL Result in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/access-distance-soql-result-in-visualforce)

I have this query `[SELECT id, DISTANCE(some_field__c, GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance FROM Parent__c LIMIT 1]` and that's working fine.

However when I try to execute this query starting from the child: 
`[SELECT id, DISTANCE(Parent__r.some_field__c, GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance FROM Child__c LIMIT 1]`
I get an error saying `No such column 'distance' on entity Child__c`. Is this a salesforce limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but try `[SELECT id, DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(Parent__r.some_field__latitude__s, Parent__r.some_field__longitude__s ), GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance FROM Child__c LIMIT 1]`. This will split out the individual latitude and longitude values from the referenced parent field.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I can't execute this query. I get a `expecting a right parentheses, found ','` for the Distance part of the query. Everything seems aright with the syntax though so i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What about something simpler, like `SELECT id, Parent__r.some_field__latitude__s, Parent__r.some_field__longitude__s FROM Child__c LIMIT 1]`

Comment: @DanielBallinger That works but I can't get the distance with this query.

Comment: Incredibly it works in the WHERE and the ORDER BY, but it does not appear in the select

Answer (score 3):

Known Issue - [Distance cannot be selected for foreign key fields](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCfK) (via @fehays)

> Distance cannot be selected for foreign key fields, for example use the below query in Apex: 
>   [SELECT id, DISTANCE(Parent__r.some_field__c, GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance FROM Child__c ], we get an error saying No such column 'distance' on entity Parent object.

---

I added a Geolocation field to Account. The following SOQL query then worked for me.

```
Select 
    Id, Account.Location__c, DISTANCE(Account.Location__c, GEOLOCATION(0,0), 'mi') distance 
from Contact 
where ID = '003700000000001'
```

So it should be possible to do distance calculations based on a parents geolocation field.

It isn't clear why mine would work and yours would fail. Try removing the `distance` alias from the SOQL query. Also, check you API versions.

Comment: It works as a query but try to execute it in anonymous apex. I assign this query to an object, let's call it `myObject`.

Then I try `Decimal distance = (Decimal)myObject.distance;` to get that distance. 

My query works inside the Query Editor but not inside the anonymous apex.

Comment: @Arthlete There appears to be a bug in Apex. Do you have access to support?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: I contacted support and they have identified it as a bug.  Here's a link to the known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCfK